# Strange behavior of the form change of the password in ie

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I use sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. In the form of the password change has three fields:

> current password,  new password,  repeat new password.

If the current is correct, and the new and repeat the same, I do

```
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->setPassword($this->form->getValue('password'));
$this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->save();
```

In all browsers except ie everything is OK, but in ie when `save()` is - or revalidation form, or redirect to the same route.

As a result, there is a new check of the current password with the old data (and then have a new password), throws out an error of the form.
Tell me what to do, I do not understand how the browser can affect server actions.

```php
public function executeChangePassword(sfWebRequest $request) {
        $this->forward404Unless($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated());
        $this->form = new ChangePasswordForm();
        $this->bSuccess = false;

        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            $this->form->bind($request->getParameter($this->form->getName()));
            if ($this->form->isValid()) {
                $this->oUser = $this->getUser();
                $this->oUser->setPassword($this->form->getValue('password'));
                $this->bSuccess = true;
            }
        }
}
```

```php
class ChangePasswordForm extends BaseForm {
    public function configure() {
        $this->setWidgets(array(
            'current_password' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'b-input-text')),
            'password' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'b-input-text')),
            'password_again' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array(), array('class' => 'b-input-text')),
        ));

        $this->validatorSchema['current_password'] = new slValidatorUserPassword(
            array('required' => true,
                'min_length' => 6,
                'max_length' => 128
            )
        );
        $this->validatorSchema['password'] = new sfValidatorString(
            array(
                'required' => true,
                'min_length' => 6,
                'max_length' => 128
            )
        );
        $this->validatorSchema['password_again'] = new sfValidatorString(
            array('required' => true,
                'min_length'    => 6,
                'max_length'    => 128
            )
        );
        $this-> mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', '==', 'password_again', array(), array()));
        $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('change_password[%s]');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using the built-in forgot_password system or a custom one? Can we see the generated html form & your action to handle the form?

Comment: Added up action. Yep, custom action. ChangePasswordForm extends BaseForm.

Comment: Can you add `ChangePasswordForm` class too?

Comment: update ChangePasswordForm

Comment: Every thing seems ok to me, what about the template which displays the form?

Comment: No, usually a form template. The strange thing is that the case in the browser. As if the listener is to update the password field, but it is not. I will look, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the provided **sfGuardChangeUserPasswordForm** class. It is included in the plugin.

Here's a working controller example:

```
public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $sf_user = $this->getUser();
    $sf_guard_user = $sf_user->getGuardUser();
    $this->form = new sfGuardChangeUserPasswordForm($sf_guard_user);

    if ("changepassword" == $request->getParameter('do'))
    { /* dont forget to put action="/route/to/this/controler/?do=changepassword" on the view's <form> */ 
        $this->processForm($request, $this->form);
    }
}

protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
{
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()), $request->getFiles($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $notice = 'Password updated successfully.';

        try {
            $sf_guard_user = $form->save();
        } catch (Doctrine_Validator_Exception $e) {

            $errorStack = $form->getObject()->getErrorStack();

            $message = get_class($form->getObject()) . ' has ' . count($errorStack) . " field" . (count($errorStack) > 1 ? 's' : null) . " with validation errors: ";
            foreach ($errorStack as $field => $errors)
            {
                $message .= "$field (" . implode(", ", $errors) . "), ";
            }
            $message = trim($message, ', ');

            $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', $message);
            return sfView::SUCCESS;
        }

        $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'admin.save_object', array('object' => $sf_guard_user)));

        $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', $notice);

        $this->redirect(array('sf_route' => 'sf_guard_user_profile'));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'Password was not changed due to some errors.', false);
    }
}
```